How to open camera in Jetpack Compose when a button is Clicked?
I'm trying to learn Android development and I saw a lot of videos in Youtube on how to make a Camera app but none of them used a button to open the camera.
I tried to make a CameraPreviewScreen but i cannot pass it inside an "onClick" function

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is how I start the camera in my app. Don't forget the permission.
private fun startCamera(
    context: Context,
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    previewView: PreviewView,
    onScan: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val cameraController = LifecycleCameraController(context)
    val options = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
        .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS)
        .build()

    val barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options)
    val mlKitAnalyzer = MlKitAnalyzer(
        listOf(barcodeScanner),
        COORDINATE_SYSTEM_VIEW_REFERENCED,
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context)
    ) { result ->
        val barcodeResult = result?.getValue(barcodeScanner)
        val scannedBarcodeValue = barcodeResult?.firstOrNull()?.rawValue ?: ""
        onScan(scannedBarcodeValue)
    }
    cameraController.setImageAnalysisAnalyzer(
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
        mlKitAnalyzer
    )
    cameraController.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner)
    previewView.controller = cameraController
}

And:
 val cameraController: LifecycleCameraController =
        remember { LifecycleCameraController(context) }
 val previewView: PreviewView = remember { PreviewView(context) }
 val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

        Column {
            val localView = LocalView.current
            Box(
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(0.5f)
            ) {
                AndroidView(
                    factory = { previewView },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(500.dp)
                )
                IconButton(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                        .padding(16.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        localView.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK)
                        startCamera(context, lifecycleOwner, previewView) { value ->
                            result = value
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Camera,
                        contentDescription = "Camera",
                        tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(54.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

You would need to adapt the camera for your needs. I am using mine as a barcode scanner.

I'm having issues here:
onClick = {
localView.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK)
startCamera(context, lifecycleOwner, previewView) { value ->
result = value
}
startCamera(context, lifecycleOwner, previewView)
"Expecting an expression"

I have added a bit more code which I hope will help.

I'm still having issue with the context, thanks for the help tho :)

val context = LocalContext.current

Excellent news!
